# \pounds produces £, but Adobe Reader needs to search for $

Tags: symbols

I've read some of the similar questions - with $ being produced instead of £. I couldn't find anything that addresses the particular issue I'm currently having though...

LaTeX quite happily produces the £ symbol when I use \pounds. However, I had the need to search the resulting PDF document to track down where this symbol was used - and Adobe Reader's search function duly reported no instances of it, anywhere. On the other hand, if I search for $, it will find all instances of £ without any problems. Is this a known bug/feature (of LaTeX and/or Adobe Reader)? Is there anything I can do to overcome it? MWE below...

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\pounds
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have Adobe Reader, so can't check this. (It works fine in xpdf and evince.) But try `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: @ArTourter --- I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question. Moreover, your deleted answer fixes the problem on my machine.

Comment: @IanThompson I deleted my answer and pointed out to the duplicate since the problem and the answer are pretty much the same. the font is different, but the underlying problem is identical.

Comment: @ArTourter I voted to undelete your answer.  Although the solution is the same, the symptoms are different enough to warrant a separate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the font encoding to `T1` for this to work. Simply add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

to your preamble

Comment: Thankyou, that works perfectly.

Which leaves me now wondering why it is necessary. Is it a bug in LaTeX? If I type(set) a £ symbol (and more to the point, the £ symbol is what is 'printed'), why does it not get interpreted as such when I search the PDF document?

Comment: This is not so much a bug as a caveat inherited due to historical reasons. There is a rather good explanation on wikibook about this (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Font_encoding). Basically, originally, LaTeX output was mostly postscript and the original encoding (`OT1`) was created so the output looked correct. The pdf format only came out later and with it new requirements. the `encguide.pdf` in your distro should also give you a more in depth idea of the concept of font encoding.